# Can't implement jump animation between GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to implement a jump animation between squares inside GridView. Like this

[image]

I have tried using Hero and "AnimatedContainer", but they didn't work. My code only makes the container blink. Can anyone help me, please?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int location = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.1),
                ),
                child: (location == index)
                    ? Hero(
                        tag: 'jump',
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                          width: 7,
                          height: 7,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              location += 2;
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Jump'),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for this we need an invisible stack i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy way to get some visualEffect**

```dart
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.1),
                  ),
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: location == index
                          ? Colors.amber
                          : Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.0),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
```

---

**jump over squares**

***Result***

[image: result]

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BodyX extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<BodyX> {
  int location = 0;

  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  get circleSize => 100;
  get circle => Container(
        height: circleSize,
        width: circleSize,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      );

  ////** Calculate Size

  get totalGrid => 16;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              location++;
              if (location >= totalGrid - 1) location = 0;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: controller,
            child: Container(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              height: constraints.maxWidth / 3 * (totalGrid ~/ 3),
              color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.2),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  GridView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: totalGrid,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 3),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.1),
                        ),
                        child: const SizedBox(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  AnimatedPositioned(
                    top: (location ~/ 3) * (constraints.maxWidth / 3) +
                        ((constraints.maxWidth / 6) - circleSize * .5),
                    left: (location % 3) * (constraints.maxWidth / 3) +
                        ((constraints.maxWidth / 6) - circleSize * .5),
                    child: circle,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, but that's not what I expected. I need moving object animation especially jump over a few squares.

Comment: then we need animatedPosition and Stack

Comment: do we need a Scrollable  widget here, like gridView?  Or is it ok  just to be fit in screenSize.